# How to avoid spaces between to rows while generating report in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

While generating report  there was a unnecessary space between two rows , if count increases then space also increases. So now how to avoid those spaces.

I here by attached screen shot.

[image]
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given this a bit of a guess; are you trying to map some records into those spaces, where the fields in CRM are null?

Try using a different field or populating those fields.

Comment: No its not null. Status of lead response is an drop down field..
I have Industry field , Status of lead response  , and some other fields. In report i need to show total number of status of response for particular industry.
In report i used Total number count of industry then count of status. then i got those result as shown in image.